# Hearing audio during a phone call in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, uiwebview, ios7

I have an app which is only a web view but the web view streaming live audio. In app I arrenged the app could stream on background in info.plist. As I said in the subject when the phone received a call the sound stops after that I pick up the call and the app starts again to stream audio during all phone call.

Is this a iOS 7 bug or what?

The code is just this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_radyoWebView.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_radyoWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: Oh wait, the audio is played _during the call_ even while your app is in background? That does sound like a bug which you might want to [report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is happening.